# How to set class attributes in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, setattribute

Python has a `setattr` to set public attributes for any class on the fly.

So, how to do that with VB.net ?

I mean :

```
Public Class abc
  ...
End Class

' Set it as :
abc.setattr("prop", 5)

' Use it as :
Dim ob As New abc
value = abc.prop
```

Is that possible with VB.net - If yes, Please explain how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such feature in VB.NET.  You have to define *Properties* manually.

For instance - [Anonymous types.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384767.aspx)

```
Dim obj = New With {.No = 10, .Name = ""}
obj.Name = "Mr.X"
```

Or

Named types

```
 Public Class Abc
     Public Property No As Integer
     Public Property Name As String
 End Class
```

Comment: You could recreate setattr in vb using reflection

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using the DLR and Dynamic objects like AVD showed.

However something like [impromptu-interface](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/) will make this eassier for you. Here is a [blog](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DesktopDev/MSTech/impromptu-interface-instead-of-clay) about it.

```
Dim c As Object = Builder.[New]()
Dim abc = c.abc(New With {.prop = 5})
```

or

```
Dim c As Object = Builder.[New]()
Dim abc = c.abc
abc.("prop") = 5
```

Which is close to what you desired.